LD_PRELOAD variable from /etc/profile is not saved in the environment when running sudo --preserve-env
Added LD_PRELOAD variable to the end of /etc/profile:
export LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libhooks.so

Then I start a new ssh session and there is a LD_PRELOAD variable in it:
[admin@Centos8 ~]$ env | grep LD_PRELOAD
LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libhooks.so

But if you run this command via sudo while saving the variables, then for some reason LD_PRELOAD is not saved:
[admin@Centos8 ~]$ sudo --preserve-env env | grep LD_PRELOAD #doesn't output anything


sudo is setuid root, and the dynamic loader (ld.so) removes variables such as LD_PRELOAD from such programs’ environment before running them. So sudo doesn’t even see your LD_PRELOAD value, and therefore can’t preserve it.
See the "Secure-execution mode" and "LD_PRELOAD" sections of man ld.so for details.
